# Twitter app created on apps.twitter.com automatically vanishes after a while

Tags: twitter, oauth

I have been struggling with this since past few hours. I am trying to get a simple twitter web app to work via oAuth. So, I head over to apps.twitter.com to create a new app, get the cosumer_key and consumer_secret. Paste it in the fields over on oauth.io. Everything works fine for a couple of minutes and then suddenly stops working. apps.twitter.com shows I have no apps and I need to create one. What is going on? Has anyone faced something like this before ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [reoccurring problem](https://twittercommunity.com/t/rate-limit-exceed-in-creating-new-app-at-apps-twitter-com/34985/16). If you try to create another app with the same name, does it tell you that an app with that name already exists? If so, your app will probably reappear on that page after a couple of hours.
In my experience, this type of hiccup only happens on registration - after it reappears, it's stable and you can use your OAuth tokens anytime you want.
Unfortunately, there's not really anything you can do to speed this up.

If the page still tells you that you don't have any apps after 24 hours, try another account or contact the Twitter support.